# How to debug a LEX/FLEX program on Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, flex-lexer, lex

How can I debug a LEX/FLEX program on Linux? The code for compilation and running is following:

```
lex example.l
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
./a.out
<Enter your input>
```

Does the `-d` token will debug LEX/FLEX? If yes, at which line do I need to include it in the code for compilation?

Answer (score 5):

You use `-d` on the flex command line (as `lex -d example.l` -- assuming your lex is actually flex, which it is on linux).  This enables debug mode by default, which will print out information about each token as it is recognized.

You can turn debuging mode on and off dynamically within the lexer by changing the global variable `yy_flex_debug` -- setting it to zero turns debug printing off and setting it to non-zero turns it back on.

You can also include the debugging code even if you don't use `-d` by compiling the generated C code with `-DFLEX_DEBUG`, though in this case `yy_flex_debug` will default to being 0, so you'll need to set it to non-zero somewhere (in your main function? or elsewhere) to enable the debugging -- having a command line option to your program that sets it is a good approach.

Comment: It is perhaps also worth noting that by `flex` also emits `#line` directives to allow for normal source-level debugging of the action code, in which a '-g' option to `gcc` would be helpful. Presumably the OP already knows this but the question is a bit unclear about just what _debugging_ signifies in this context.

Comment: If you don't use `-d`, the generated scanner won't include code that tests `yy_flex_debug` so setting it to `1` won't do anything. Hence, you _must_ use `-d`.